# How do I extract int values from string?

Tags: python, arrays, regex, list, integer

Hello I have a `list` like this:

```
B=
["('33', '207')",
 "('33', '408')",
 "('33', '408')",
 "('33', '408')",
 "'NaN'",
 "('33', '207')"]
```

I would like to return an array of integers, like the following:

```
B1 =
    [33, 207,
     33, 408,
     33, 408,
     33, 408,
     NaN, Nan,
     33, 408]
```

I am trying to use `regex` as `B1[0]=re.findall(r'\d+', B[0])`

Comment: NaNs are part of the IEEE 754 standard for floating point number. So, you cannot create `array of integer` with NaN value inside it (well, in python you can but then it wouldn't be an array of integer only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use split:

```
B1 = [(float(a[1]),float(a[-2])) for a in (b.split("'") for b in B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel. However, I can also have:

```
B= ["('31', '265')",
 "('31', '265')",
 "('31', '265')",
 "('31', '265')",
 "('31', '265')",
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan,
 nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the strings to tuple of string digits then use `numpy.array()` and `array.astype()` to convert the tuples to arrays of float, if the type of the item is tuple (check the type using `isinstance()` and else repeat the item and convert to float type):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([np.array(i).astype(float) if isinstance(i,tuple) else np.repeat(np.array(i).astype(float),2) for i in map(literal_eval,B)])
array([[  33.,  207.],
       [  33.,  408.],
       [  33.,  408.],
       [  33.,  408.],
       [  nan,   nan],
       [  33.,  207.]])
```